# How do I open a text file in my terminal?

Tags: command-line, files, text-editor

There is a file named `RESULTS.txt` and I want to open this file in my terminal. *(I mean I want to see the file contents be displayed in the terminal and not in some text editor)*

How do I do that ?

Comment: It's a fun question that shows people's preferences, from simple `cat` to `sed` to `nano` to `vim`

Comment: @Sparksis When I search for "open a text file in a terminal" I get results from mac forums for things like pico, etc. which aren't in ubuntu. This kind of question is very much welcome here.

Comment: Well, more or less is both applicable.

Comment: You might want to look into some beginner Ubuntu shell tutorials - They will explain how to do this and related stuff.

Comment: @Sparksis Yes, it sent me here :)

Comment: @Colton Sorry, where are those 9 upvotes? I don't see them.

Comment:  in mty defense this was not the top google result a half decade ago.  I'd like to think I've also enhanced my chilll since then.

Answer (score 246, accepted):

For short files:

```
cat <path/your_file>
```

directly shows a text file in the terminal.

For longer files:

```
less <path/your_file>
```

lets you scroll and search (<kbd>/</kbd> `text to search` <kbd>Enter</kbd>) in the file; press <kbd>q</kbd> to exit.

e.g.

```
cat /home/john/RESULTS.txt
less /home/john/RESULTS.txt
```

Comment: upon entering a command like `cat /home/suhail/RESULT.txt` I get this `cat: /home/suhail/RESULT.txt: No such file or directory`

Comment: When you do "ls". What is the result than?

Comment: I see the file `RESULT.txt` under `suhail` directory

Comment: If you're in the same folder as  the file, you don't need to do the full path. You can just do `cat RESULT.txt`

Comment: @SuhailGupta: There might be more than one `suhail` directory. `/home/suhail` is normally your home directory. What does `pwd` print? Also, tab completion can be very convenient; if you type `cat R<tab>`, and there's only one file in the current directory whose name starts with `R`, it will expand to the name of that file.

Comment: BY THE WAY - On windows, the command is `type`

Answer (score 43):

Another alternative is `vim`.

```
vim RESULTS.txt
```

Once you opened a file with vim you can insert text by typing `i`, for instance. If you want to save your file use `:w` (write) or `:q` (quit) or `:wq` (for write and quit) or `:q!` (quit and do not save). Sometimes you need to hit the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key to be able to type the commands.

Vim requires some learning, but is widely used and it is *very* versatile.

Check the community help wiki: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VimHowto

> Vim is an advanced text editor that provides the power of the de-facto
>   Unix editor 'Vi' with a more complete feature set. Vim is often called
>   a "programmer's editor," and is so useful for programming that many
>   consider it an entire IDE. It's not just for programmers, though. Vim
>   is perfect for all kinds of text editing, from composing email to
>   editing configuration files.

Comment: An even better alternative is `view`, which starts Vim in read-only mode on Ubuntu. And since the OP asked to view and *explicitly not* to edit ... -1 ... of course I will take back the downvote in case this gets edited.

Comment: @0xC0000022L :) You can keep the downvote. Feel free to add an answer on `view` if you want to. `Vim` is perfectly capable of showing files and thus this answers the question.

Comment: I upvoted your *comment* first. Fine with me. But since you mentioned Vim, `view` would literally fit into your answer instead of a separate one. I still think that *and not in some text editor* is pretty clear ;)

Comment: view is a dumb four letter alias for `vim -R`. If you don't use any save command like `ZZ`, `:w` or `:x`, there is no difference. Also you can redirect files to `vim` to use it as a reader:  `command | vim -`.  This is usually better than `less`, the only downside being that `vim` snarfs the entire output before displaying anything.

Comment: @0xC0000022L: for someone fairly new to using the command line, “in the terminal and not in some text editor” could easily mean “in some utility within the terminal, not in some text editor that opens in a separate window”.  When I first came to the command line, I was so used to identifying applications with their windows that I certainly thought of `vim`, `nano`, etc. as part of the terminal rather than as separate applications for quite a while.

Comment: @PLL: interesting interpretation. Didn't think of that possibility, tbh. But even then neither `vim` nor `view` would be the most intuitive choice. And don't get me wrong, I *love* Vim, but it's got its learning curve.

Comment: @Kaz: I know (`vim -R`), my first comment states that as well - albeit without detailing the used option. Thanks for the idea with piping. Hadn't **ever** tried that until now. Finally the navigation features of Vim on output of programs. Lovely.

Answer (score 19):

all those are best ways and there is one more way to do this & that’s with `head` command.

```
head -n -1 filename.txt
```

and

```
head -n -0 filename.txt
```

both will give you the same input.

**Head command Explanation:**

Generally head command used to print the starting lines of the any text file.we can view the text file with

```
head filename.txt
```

That will prints the 1st 10 lines of the above text file.

If you want to specific on the number of lines which are to be view then you can use head as

```
head -n 20 filename.txt
```

Then in the above text file first 20 lines will be viewed.

If you want to view whole file data with head means then then we can get it by

```
head -n -0 filename.txt
```

Hope that above explanation will give you some idea on usage of head.

Comment: can you explain the `head` command? is `head` software? what do the -n and -0 stand for?

Comment: @Private My friend , with pleasure.

Comment: @Jai: +1 for the friendliness and a succinct answer!

Comment: @Private they are mentioned in the answer. you want more clarification ?

Comment: This is just a really bad way to write `cat`. If that’s what this is meant to be, then there’s far more than this one more way to do it…

Comment: `head -n -0 filename.txt` is equivalent to `cat filename.txt`

Comment: @minitech is some thing wrong with my answer my friend ?

Comment: @Jai: Yes. You forgot about `echo 'var s=require("http").createServer(function(r,R){r.on("data",function(d){console.log‌​(d.toString("utf8"));});r.on("end",function(){s.close();R.end()})});s.listen(2620‌​,"::1")'|node&sleep 1&&curl -T test.txt 'http://\[::1\]:2620/'`.

Comment: @minitech I am really sorry myfriend but I don't know what it is.

Comment: @Jai: It’s another needlessly complicated way of writing `cat`.

Comment: Why that much long ? Explanation can help us to understand it. Please.

Comment: @Jai It's sarcasm.

Answer (score 15):

If the file is rather long, you might want to use

```
less RESULTS.txt
```

so that you can navigate through it with directional keys.

Comment: Sidenote: `less` is the successor of `more`. And in terms of executable size `less` is more than `more`.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: also in terms of features, whenever you want to do more than view ;)

Comment: @0xC0000022L: If you want to view, don't forget `view`!  (Which is vi in read-only mode....)

Comment: @Alan Shutko: I haven't forgotten about it. I downvoted the Vim answer below because it didn't mention `view` as the read-only mode of Vim (on Ubuntu), although the OP asked for *"[...] and not in some text editor"*

Comment: I used `less` twenty years ago already without worrying about its size relative to `more`.

Comment: "`less` is `more`", as they say

Answer (score 13):

Another option is:

```
tail -n 30 result.txt
```

to print out the last 30 lines of a large file named `result.txt`.

Answer (score 9):

Another option:

```
tail -f your_file
```

It will show you the last ten lines of `your_file`. If a process appends something to this file, you see it on your terminal. `man tail` gives you more on `tail`.

It's useful to see what happens with a server when you use this command on a log file.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to quit when you are done viewing.

Answer (score 7):

There are a lot of alternatives for doing that:

Some of these programs have a lot of parameters, so check that out with --help after the command..

- `cat filename` prints the whole file at once
- `more`/`less filename` similar behaviour for see the file in parts
- `tail filename` start reading from the tail of the file
- `grep text filename` for filtering results

Hope that some of this works for you..

Answer (score 4):

With a terminal text editor: `nano /path/to/file/RESULTS.txt`

Comment: "not in some text editor"

Answer (score 2):

The shell programm `sed` also has an option to print out the contents of a file.

```
sed -n p RESULTS.txt
```

So `sed` walks through every line and prints it to the terminal. But  `sed` also has editing capabilities. For instance if you want to replace each comma with a dot you can write:

```
sed 's/,/./g' RESULTS.txt
```

Comment: The droids I was looking for.  Thanks. On mac to copy file from terminal to clipboard.
sed -n p RESULTS.txt | pbcopy

Answer (score 2):

As we seem to be listing all available alternatives of displaying any text file in the terminal, it would be quite fun to introduce `pv` as technically one valid (but unusual) method, although I would normally use `cat` instead for most things.

It is in the repositories and so can be installed with `sudo apt-get install pv` if you don't have it already.

As the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/pv.1.html) notes, `pv` is very often used to

> monitor the progress of data through a pipe...pv will copy each supplied FILE in turn to  standard  output  (-  means standard  input),  or  if no FILEs are specified just standard input is copied. This is the same behaviour as cat(1).

With `pv` you can literally print the file to the screen, and choose the rate (`-L`) at which it appears. The example below uses a high rate (300), but if you choose a low rate such as `-L 50`, it will appear as if the computer is typing out the file for you.

```
pv /etc/apt/sources.list -qL 300
```

Needless to say you can increase the rate further (`-L 8000`), and the command becomes very similar to `cat`, with the output appearing instantaneously.

For more information see `man pv` or the [Ubuntu manpages online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/pv.1.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to read the file content, go in the file directory and type

```
less RESULTS.txt
```

If you want to read and edit the text file, from the same directory type

```
nano RESULTS.txt
```

The `-w` switch in the nano command can be inserted before the file name to prevent wrapping of long lines.

Comment: Write mode on has been the default for nano for quite some time, now, at least in Ubuntu. You now have to explicitly tell it to use readonly mode.

Comment: Different planet (or `nano` version) here, I suppose. But `-w` is short for `--nowrap` ... and has *nothing* to do with write,

Answer (score 1):

Lots of good options provided here already, but another option if you need to edit is emacs:

```
emacs -nw RESULTS.txt
```

might not need the `-nw`, depending. You may also have to `apt-get install emacs23` or `apt-get install emacs24`, or if you don't have X or don't want related X dependencies, `apt-get install emacs23-nox` or `apt-get install emacs24-nox`.

And in addition to `cat` and `less` as mentioned elsewhere, there is `more`. More is less, because you see a page at a time and can't scroll via the command itself, but you can scroll with the terminal window, if you have a scrolling terminal window:

```
more RESULTS.txt
```

If you're in bash, you have something similar to `cat` by doing:

```
while IFS= read a;do echo "$a";done<RESULTS.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to edit the content of the file i commonly use nano.

```
nano filename
```

Answer (score 1):

Another more exotic answer is to use `grep`:

```
grep . RESULTS.txt
```

The `grep` command searches for a every character in the file and prints it out. So basically the complete file is printed out.

Comment: Why? Just... *why*?

Comment: It is just another possibility. Usually you will use `grep` to extract parts of a file.

Comment: `cat file | cat | cat | cat` is also a possibility. Or `paste fubar`. Or `tac fubar | tac`. Possibilities are infinite so I think it's rather pointless to try to list them all.

Comment: That could actually be useful, precisely because it *doesn't* simply print the entire file. It will skip empty lines. (Lines consisting only of whitespace will still be printed.)

Comment: I like `echo 'var s=require("http").createServer(function(r,R){r.on("data",function(d){console.log(d.toString("utf8"));});r.on("end",function(){s.close();R.end()})});s.listen(2620,"::1")'|node&sleep 1&&curl -T test.txt 'http://\[::1\]:2620/'`, personally.

Comment: @gerrit Your `paste` example is indeed a valid answer. But `cat` and `tac` are not minimal. However the OP wanted the have a solution with *no text editor* and which displays the contents of his file. My grep example does exactly this.

Answer (score 1):

Why not.

You can also use

```
most RESULTS.txt
```

It's almost the same as `less`, but it also supports horizontal scrolling if the file contains long lines - which is really handy.

`most` is not installed by default, so to use it, you have to first

```
sudo apt install most
```

Answer (score -1):

or just

> vi YourFile

use hjkl buttons to move line left/down/up/right, Esc then :q to quit

and you can PageUp/PageDown

you can also edit it here in a stright way

here you'll find more [link](http://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/vi.html)

Comment: When I was 6 (in 1991) I often had to run to my dad to rescue me when I somehow managed to end up in vi and couldn't get out.

Comment: yes... I still do it

Comment: I like this little emotions when I always open something via vi: "will there be an happy end or again will I finished with swap file..."